# How to adjust size of inline images on Gmail using AppScript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail

I have the built the below code to send email with inline hyperlinked images and want to adjust the size of the inline image (make it smaller)

```
      MailApp.sendEmail({ 
      to: CurrentEmail,
      name: 'Name',
      subject: subjectLine, 
      body: messageBody,
      attachments: [email_Attachment_1,email_Attachment_2],
      htmlBody: messageBody+"<BR/><BR/>"+"<a href=\"" + linkedin_url + "\"><img src=\"cid:linkedIn\">"+"<BR/><BR/>"+"<a href=\"" + pwcacademy_url + "\"><img src=\"cid:pwcacademy\">"+"<BR/><BR/>"+"<a href=\"" + pwc_url + "\"><img src=\"cid:pwc\">",
      inlineImages: {linkedIn: linkedin_logo, pwcacademy: pwcacademy_logo, pwc: pwc_logo}
    });
```

The size of pwcacademy is relatively bigger and I want to make the size small without compromising the quality of the inline image (see below). Any guidance is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: have you tried inline styling width="100px" height="100px"

Comment: Where can I insert it that piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to go about doing this. The first one involves using inline-styles.

```
htmlBody: messageBody+"<BR/><BR/>"+"<a href=\"" + pwcacademy_url + "\"><img src=\"cid:pwcacademy\" style='width:24px; height:16px;'>",
```

and the other involves adding direct width and height without inline style.

```
htmlBody: messageBody+"<BR/><BR/>"+"<a href=\"" + pwcacademy_url + "\"><img src=\"cid:pwcacademy\" width='24px' height='16px'>",
```

specifying width and height in the image tag is a good practice and this way when the page loads there is space allocated for the image and the layout does not suffer any jerks even if the image takes a long time to load.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. Thanks to @Mr. Khan

```
      htmlBody: messageBody+"<BR/><BR/>"+"<a href=\"" + pwcacademy_url + "\"><img src=\"cid:pwcacademy\" style='width:24px; height:16px;'>",
```